# ¿Cómo habilitar inputs solamente de una fila seleccionada en una tabla HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Estoy tratando de habilitar inputs al darle clic al botón "Editar". Solamente quiero que se habiliten los de la fila seleccionada en la tabla, y mi problema es que al darle clic al botón me habilita todos los inputs de todas las filas.

Les dejo mi código php y html:

```
`if (isset($_POST['btnEdit'])) {
        $id = $_POST['btnEdit'];
        $enabled = 'enabled';
        echo 'Has actualizado el registro con id: ' . $id;
    }`

`<tr>
                                        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente" value="<?php echo $row['num_cliente']; ?>" <?php echo $enabled; ?>></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>" <?php echo $enabled; ?>></td>
                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" value="<?php echo $row['apellidos']; ?>" <?php echo $enabled; ?>></td>
                                        <td><input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" name="correo" value="<?php echo $row['correo']; ?>" <?php echo $enabled; ?>></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1" title="Guardar" name="btnSave" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="far fa-save fa-lg"></i></button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-1" title="Editar" name="btnEdit" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1" title="Eliminar" name="btnDelete" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i></button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>`
```

[image]

Espero y me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo usar ajax y los input como arreglos `name="cliente[]" ` para identificar la fila que se va habilitar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde PHP asignas el atributo `disabled` a todos los `inputs`, con *JQuery* detectas qué botón fue el que recibió clic para poder activar solo los `inputs` que estén en la misma fila que el botón.

```js
// Activar edición cuando se haga clic en un botón "Editar"
$('.btn-info').on('click', function(e) {
    // Evitar comportamiento normal del evento (¿submit?)
    e.preventDefault();
    // Desactivar todos los campos de la tabla
    $('#mi-tabla input').prop('disabled', true);
    // Buscar solo los campos en esta fila y activar
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="mi-tabla">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente" value="<?php echo $row['num_cliente']; ?>" disabled></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>"  disabled></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" value="<?php echo $row['apellidos']; ?>"  disabled></td>
        <td><input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" name="correo" value="<?php echo $row['correo']; ?>" disabled></td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1" title="Guardar" name="btnSave" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="far fa-save fa-lg"></i></button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-1" title="Editar" name="btnEdit" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1" title="Eliminar" name="btnDelete" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente" value="<?php echo $row['num_cliente']; ?>" disabled></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>"  disabled></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" value="<?php echo $row['apellidos']; ?>"  disabled></td>
        <td><input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" name="correo" value="<?php echo $row['correo']; ?>" disabled></td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1" title="Guardar" name="btnSave" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="far fa-save fa-lg"></i></button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-1" title="Editar" name="btnEdit" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1" title="Eliminar" name="btnDelete" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="cliente" name="cliente" value="<?php echo $row['num_cliente']; ?>" disabled></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>"  disabled></td>
        <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" value="<?php echo $row['apellidos']; ?>"  disabled></td>
        <td><input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" name="correo" value="<?php echo $row['correo']; ?>" disabled></td>
        <td>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm mt-1" title="Guardar" name="btnSave" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="far fa-save fa-lg"></i></button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-sm mt-1" title="Editar" name="btnEdit" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i></button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1" title="Eliminar" name="btnDelete" value="<?php echo $row['idCliente']; ?>"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i></button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Coincido con lo que comentó @MRDev, deberías usar AJAX para actualizar la fila modificada.